# How to convert a parse date object to a string?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

*beginner alert*

I'm trying to query for a date from PFUser and then format it to NSDate so it is more useful. The trouble begins when I try to convert the object to a NSString so I can format it with NSDateFormatter()

```
    var user = PFUser.query()
    user.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    user.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {
                var lastActive = object["lastActive"]
                if lastActive != nil {   
                let newLastActive = lastActive as String //problem starts here!!
                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
                let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(newLastActive)
                println("new date \(date)")
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way of doing this? Also, if I don't specify the variable type as AnyObject, it keeps coming out as a optional. How do I get rid of the optional while converting it to String?

edit: the object "lastActive" is a date set by parse cloud, not a string.

Comment: Does your lastActive field in parse store a date or a string?

Comment: it stores a date just like "createdAt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your lastActive cell returns a date you could use:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(lastActive as NSDate)
```

You dont have to cast your date to string, you will create a date string via the dateformatter.
But if you do so, you could use `lastActive as! String` insted of `lastActive as String`

**UPDATED**

```
for object in objects {
            var lastActive = object["lastActive"]
            if lastActive != nil {
                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
                let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(lastActive as NSDate)
                println(date)
            }
        }
```

I tried with this code above and if you've set your column in parse to date, it should work.

Comment: the xcode error comes up as "cannot convert 'AnyObject?!' to type '$T3' on the line of the dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newlastActive) :(

Comment: I made an error, you should use the lastActive in stringFromDate, as that stores the date as a date

Comment: the same error still occurs. This is because the objects returned from the query are all "AnyObjects" I believe.

Comment: I updated my code according to it. So it casts the date to NSDate

Comment: error is now: NSDate is not a subtype of NSString. Thanks for trying though

Comment: are you sure you use lastActive and not newLastActive in the dateformatter? because as you said, lastActive is a date type not a string type, and the error above suggest that you use some kind of string instead of a date

Comment: yes..i did use lastActive. I think you're forgetting the fact that any object returned from parse is a AnyObject. Doesn't matter if it is stored in a date format or any other ones.

Comment: No, it does matter. If you store in the cloud the date as date, you would recive an AnyObject just like you did, but then you can cast it to an NSDate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66808/discussion-between-user3483697-and-daniel-nagy).

Comment: I'm using Swift2 and iOS9.1. Im getting an error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Any ideas?

Comment: `let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(createdAt as! NSDate)`

Comment: @rinyfo4 are you sure that your column on Parse, which's data stored in `createdAt` has a type of `Date`?

Comment: Hmm, I will take a look at it at the evening, I'm not near my computer right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93291/discussion-between-rinyfo4-and-daniel-nagy).