# How to query and convert Parse.com Date to NSDate/String

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to take the parse column "`createdAt`", query it and make it into a string that displays on the UI as a label to show the user when a product was posted and when it expires.

There are similar questions on stackoverflow, but none have helped me and all have given me errors and crashes.

I am using a `TableViewController` class and I'm querying 2 things: the `productName` and the `timeCreated`. (The `productName` I'm able to display in a cell without a problem.)

I've tried several ways of getting the date:

Here is the first way. I tried querying it WITH the other Parse object:

```
var productName = [String]()

var timeCreated = [NSDate]()

//Arrays above the viewDidLoad() to store the productName and the   timeCreated

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    var query = PFQuery(className: "ProductInfo")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) -> Void in

    if let objects = objects {

        self.productName.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.timeCreated.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        for object in objects {

            self.productName.append(object["pName"] as! String)

            self.timeCreated.append(object["createdAt"] as! NSDate)



            print(self.productName)
            print(self.timeCreated)

            self.tableView.reloadData()


            }


        }


    })


}
```

The second way I'm trying is to query it separately from the `productName` object on its own, using this code. Ultimately formatting it, and then converting it into a string with `stringFromDate`. Im not putting it into an array, but I'm assuming I should as well if i want to use it?? This is the link I tried but didn't help: [How to convert a parse date object to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457411/how-to-convert-a-parse-date-object-to-a-string) Like this:

```
 var dateQuery = PFQuery(className:"ProductInfo")

    dateQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

        for object in objects {
            var createdAt = object["createdAt"]
            if createdAt != nil {
                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
                let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(createdAt as! NSDate)
                print(date)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This is also in the `viewDidLoad` method, but just below the first query.

The error I'm getting is this: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` for both ways.

It highlights this line in the first way I tried: 
`self.timeCreated.append(object["createdAt"] as! NSDate)`

and this line for the 2nd way I did it: 
`let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(createdAt as! NSDate)`

Why is it giving me an error? Any ideas on who to query it and convert it into a string (in an array) that I can use?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: This was asked and answered a hundred times. It's basic Swift behaviour. If you don't know why this happens, you need to learn Swift.

Comment: I understand why it's happening. However, I don't know how to get rid of it and actually query the date. Thats my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The created at date is like a private parameter of the `PFObject`, so you should use the accessor function provided rather than try to access it like a generic container. So, change your code to:

```
self.timeCreated.append(object.createdAt as NSDate)
```

Comment: I get an error: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSDate?!" to expected argument type 'NSDate' I've tried down casting it as well.

Comment: It's a nullable property in obj-c, and technically it won't exist for explicitly created objects that aren't uploaded yet, but in your case it's safe to unpack

Comment: Yup, worked. thanks! How would I convert it now into a string?

Comment: Using an `NSDateFormatter` like you have, your issue was never formatting it was simply accessing the variable properly

Comment: small question: I'm getting a warning on the line you posted above on the `as` telling me to downcast. For now I made it `as! NSDate!` because if not, i an error. Anyway to get rid of the error? Ive tried various combinations.

Comment: What version of swift are you using? you shouldn't need 2 !, just as! should suffice (you're telling it to force unpack), different versions of swift handle it in different ways (so it's hard to keep up)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93294/discussion-between-rinyfo4-and-wain).

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM'-'dd'-'yyyy'"

let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate((<yourParseObjectHere>.createdAt as NSDate?)!)
yourLabel.text = date
```